# Can not log {aspnet-request-posted-body} with NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, nlog

I try to using ${aspnet-request-post-body} to log the request body in log file, but I got this exception before into controller:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.ReadOnlyStream.get_Position()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream.get_Position()
   at NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware.ShouldCaptureRequestBody(HttpContext context)
   at NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext ontext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, waggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware.InvokeInternal(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My code is below:

Program.cs

```
try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<Service>();

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseHttpLogging();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    // TODO logger output request body
    // needed for  ${aspnet-request-posted-body} with an API Controller.
    app.UseMiddleware<NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>(
               new NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddlewareOptions());

   // app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

    app.MapControllers();

    NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings();

    app.Run();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Error(e, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Controller：

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _cache = cache;
}

[HttpPost("GetWeatherForecast")]
public ActionResult<WeatherForecast> Post(List<GeoInfo> coordinates)
{
    _logger.LogError("error");
    return Ok();
}

public class GeoInfo
{
    [Required]
    [Range(20, 25, ErrorMessage = "The field out of range.")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(118, 123, ErrorMessage = "The field out of range.")]
    public double Lon { get; set; }
}
```

}

appsettings.json

```
{
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "logfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "./log/${shortdate}.txt"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft.AspNetCore",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

environment: asp.net.core with .net6, NLog.Web.AspNetCore 5.3.1.

I tried to change the UseMiddleware on different line I thought it maybe startup queue problem but it's not. I also found the [document](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) but still can't figure out why.

Comment: Was not able to repro. Can you please post the full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @GuruStron I added the controller code, I also created an empty project the problem also occur again, please let me know if I miss any information or you need.

Comment: Bug introduce with NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.3.1. Created pull-request with fix: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/962

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. New NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.3.2 has been released, that should fix the bug - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for your help, when I upgraded to 5.3.2, the exception has been fixed, but the log file does not output the request post body, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To output posted-body in the `"logfile"` then it requires 2 steps:

1. Setup `app.UseMiddleware<NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>()`
2. Update ouput `Layout`-option for `"logfile"` to include `${aspnet-request-posted-body}`

appsettings.json

```json
{
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" }
    ],
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "logfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "./log/${shortdate}.txt"
        "layout": "${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message:withexception=true}|${aspnet-request-posted-body}"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See also: [${aspnet-request-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) and other [${aspnet-extensions}](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore)

See also: [HTTP-Request-Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging)

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen, Now the post body can be output. I tried hard to make the output result as I expected, but I couldn't find how to set it. The current output format is like tracestack, and each line contains the output post body.

Comment: The result I expected It only outputs one line of information and includes all the information of the request, for example: 2023-07-06 14:53:48.5235 | Info | Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44322/api/Weather/Forecast application/json-patch +json 81 |
2023-07-06 14:53:48.5243 | Info | Request:
...request info...
Post body: [
   {
     "lat": 25,
     "lon": 123,
     "time": "2023-07-06T06:53:47.107Z"
   }
]
2023-07-06 14:53:48.7921 | Error | error message here

Comment: Sounds like you should use [UseHttpLogging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging#usehttplogging-introduced-with-net6) with `LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody`, instead of `${aspnet-request-posted-body}`.